# Does ansible-playbook use a previously created changeset if one exists or does it run using the playbooks and vars?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-cloudformation

We use ansible-playbook to create/update cloudformation stacks.
If we run the playbook with create_changeset=yes then ansible creates a changeset rather than updating the stack.

If we then run the playbook again with create_changeset=no, does it execute the changeset or does it run a normal stack update?  After we run the playbook the changeset is gone but that doesn't tell me what actually happened.

I'm hoping it does not execute the changeset because I wonder what happens if I change one or more vars between creating the changeset and executing the playbook the second time.  In that case the change to the vars would seem to be missed.

Comment: It is absolutely impossible to answer your question without any knowledge of your playbook and the potential roles it is using. Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verified that ansible-playbook with create_changeset=no just does a normal update.  The changeset is deleted but that happens anyway when you do an update.

Verified this by changing a var value, then creating a changeset, then changing the value again and running the playbook...resulting in the last var value being used rather than the var value in the changeset.

Confirmed this by looking at CloudTrails to see what actual api calls were made.